# Como crear una notificación Android Studio actualizada

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-notifications

quiero crear una notificación que se muestre al presionar un botón. 
He intentado lo siguiente que encontré, pero me parece que está obsoleto.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button mostrarNotificacion;
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         mostrarNotificacion=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnMostrarNotificacion);
         mostrarNotificacion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
                 NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =(NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                 int icono = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
                 Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this, MensajeActivity.class);
                 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0, i, 0);

                 mBuilder =new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                         .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                         .setSmallIcon(icono)
                         .setContentTitle("Titulo")
                         .setContentText("Hola que tal?")
                         .setVibrate(new long[] {100, 250, 100, 500})
                         .setAutoCancel(true);



                 mNotifyMgr.notify(1, mBuilder.build());

             }
         });
     } }
```

> ESTA LÍNEA ES LA QUE ME MARCA COMO OBSOLETA:

```
mBuilder =new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
```

MensajeActivity solo es otra clase que mostrará un TextView de que la notificación fue recibida.

Comment: Listo, soy nueva en esto, no encuentro información actualizada